Call function inside Android WebViewClient Jetpack compose
I'm working with Kotlin and Jetpack Compose.
My Code
AndroidView(factory = {
            WebView(it).apply {
                webViewClient = WebViewClient()
                Log.d("myTag", mUrl); //is called once    
            }
        }, update = {
            it.loadUrl(mUrl)
            Log.d("myTag", mUrl); //is called once 
        })

How can I call the Log.d or any other function on urlredirect? Now it's called only once, so I can browse through the web, but I can't mutate any states or whatever.

Create a subclass of WebViewClient and create an instance of it, instead of creating an instance of WebViewClient() itself. Override whichever functions you want in the subclass.
